# Многопоточный сервер не выводит сообщение в консоль

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

Пишу многопоточный сервер и почему то не могу получить ответ от сервера в консоль . В качестве клиента использую  curl -X POST -d "temperature=18" http://localhost:9000/queue/weather
Вроде бы данные попадают в out но не получаю ответа от сервера . Все переменные правильные смотрел в дебаге. В простом сервере без пула все отрабатывает верно

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


    public class Server {
    
        private final HashMap<String, Service> modes = new HashMap<>();
    
        public void start() {
            modes.put("queue", new QueueService());
            modes.put("topic", new TopicService());
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
            );
            try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9000)) {
                while (!server.isClosed()) {
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    pool.execute(() -> {
                        try (OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                             InputStream input = socket.getInputStream()) {
                            byte[] buff = new byte[1_000_000];
                            var total = input.read(buff);
                            var text = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(buff, 0, total), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                            var req = Req.of(text);
                            var resp = modes.get(req.method()).process(req);
                            var temp = ("HTTP/1.1 " + resp.status() + " OK\r\n");
                            out.write(temp.getBytes());
                            var temp2 = resp.text();
                            out.write(temp2.getBytes());
                            out.flush();
                            System.out.println("hi");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Server().start();
        }
    }

public class Req {

    private final String method;
    private final String mode;
    private final String text;

    private Req(String method, String mode, String text) {
        this.method = method;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public static Req of(String content) {
        /* TODO parse a content */
        String[] array = content.split("\r\n");
        String[] temp = array[0].split("/");
        String tempMethod = temp[1];
        String[] temp2 = temp[2].split(" ");
        String tempMode = temp2[0];
        return new Req(tempMethod, tempMode, array[7]);
    }

    public String method() {
        return method;
    }

    public String mode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public String text() {
        return text;
    }
}


public class Resp {

    private final String text;
    private final int status;

    public Resp(String text, int status) {
        this.text = text;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String text() {
        return text;
    }

    public int status() {
        return status;
    }
}

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class QueueService implements Service {

    private  ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>> queue = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public Resp process(Req req) {
        queue.putIfAbsent(req.mode(), new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>());
        queue.get(req.mode()).add(req.text());
        var result = queue.get(req.mode()).poll();
        return new Resp(result, id.incrementAndGet());
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложите весь личтинг чтоб можно было компилировать. И список библиотек которые вы используете

Comment: добавил файлы и импорт

Comment: Service, TopicService??

Comment: TopicService еще не написал  , а Service  вот - public interface Service {

    Resp process(Req req);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильно реализован протокол HTTP. Из ответа HTTP должен быть способ узнать его длину.

Нужно либо вернуть заголовок `Content-Length` - в этом случае клиент закончит обработку запроса по получению указаного количества байт.

Либо нужно вернуть заголовок `Connection: close`, тогда клиент определяет конец сообщения по закрытому соединению.

Кроме того, между заголовками и телом должны идти переводы строки.

Вот так вот приблизительно:

```
Resp resp = modes.get(req.method()).process(req);
String temp = ("HTTP/1.1 " + resp.status() + " OK\n");
out.write(temp.getBytes());
String header = "Connection: close";
out.write(header.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
out.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
String temp2 = resp.text();
out.write(temp2.getBytes());
out.flush();
```

Comment: а как это ? Еще не дошел до http

Comment: Вы реализовываете протокол HTTP, так что вы уже "дошли" до него, может, сами не осознавая :)

Comment: Благодарю)) пока еще до конца не осознал